# Can't find PIL module when using declared class

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, python-3.6

I have written a simple Python script with Pillow to generate a grid on a 1024x256 Image.

Then I define a class, which is more like a a collection of functions.

```
class Letters:

    COLOR_GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
    COLOR_BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
    COLOR_BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
    class A:
        margin_top = 64
        margin_bottom = 64
        section_margin_empty = 16
        section_margin_filled = [i for i in range(0, 15)]

        @staticmethod
        def draw(pixelarray, margin_left):

            draw_range_height = [i for i in range(margin_bottom, 256 - (6 * 16))]
            draw_range_width = [i for i in range(margin_left, margin_left + 15)]

            for j in draw_range_width:
                for i in draw_range_height:
                    if pixelarray[j, i] == (0, 0, 0):
                        pixelarray[j, i] = COLOR_GREEN

            return pixelarray
```

But the problem does not seem to be in the class...

My main code is this:

```
from PIL import Image
import os

if os.path.exists("banner.png"):
    img = Image.open("banner.png")
else:
    img = Image.new("RGB", (1024, 256), "black")

WIDTH, HEIGHT = img.size
pixels = img.load()

for i in range(0, HEIGHT):
    for j in range(0, WIDTH):
        if j % 16 == 0:
            pixels[j, i] = (0, 0, 255)
        else:
            if i % 16 == 0:
                pixels[j, i] = (0, 0, 255)
            else:
                pixels[j, i] = (0, 0, 0)

pixels = Letters.A.draw(pixels, 33)        # <= Error is here

img.save("banner.png")
```

For some reason, when I try to use the function `Letters.A.draw()` the script crashes in line 1 with an `ImportError: Module PIL not found!`

How come it does not work when I have that line in there, but when I remove it, it works fine??

The exact error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "msp.py", line 1, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
ImportError: No module named PIL
```

Comment: Are you saying that just commenting out the `pixels = Letters.A.draw(pixels, 33)` line makes your code work?  Is this all of your code?

Comment: Yes, im saying exactly that. And yes, thats all my code

Comment: It generates a blue-on-black grid, and the class is supposed to fill the black squares... Like a generator that generates virtual LCD screens.

Comment: I don't believe this is all of your code.  In particular, you never import `Letters` in your second file (unless both code samples are in the same file, in which case the import error would be after line 1).

Comment: Both are in the same file. It is all my code. And it does not "crash" technically, it just cant find the module PIL when I use that class.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the ImportError. However, in the `draw()` method you have to refer to `margin_bottom` as `Letters.A.margin_bottom`, and `COLOR_GREEN` must be referred to as `Letters.COLOR_GREEN`.

Comment: That did not work either. My code works when written outside a class, but it doesnt work when used in a class

Answer (score 0):

Appearently it seems to be an issue with the IDE.
With VisualStudio 2017 python tools it didnt work, but with LiCLipse it did.
Weird thing, but using LiClipse helped me.

Comment: Surely not entirely an IDE issue? My comment about how you refer to class variables is relevant, isn't it?

Comment: It is relevant, yes, but it didnt fix the problem. It helped correct some error that probably would have happened, but it didnt fix THAT problem

Comment: And its most likely not entirely an IDE issue, but switching IDE did fix it. I still have no idea what could have caused this.